# How can I validate email and username on my registration form. I am using flask and mysqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask

Here is my route which works great problem is i can register same user many many times:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form.get('name')
        username = request.form.get('username')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        confirm = request.form.get('confirm')
        secure_password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(password))

        if password == confirm:
            db.execute('INSERT INTO users(name, username, email, password) VALUES(:name,:username,:email,:password)',
                                           {'name':name,'username':username,'email':email,'password':secure_password})
            db.commit()
            flash("you are registerd and you can login","success")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            flash("password does not match","danger")
            return render_template('register.html')

    return render_template('register.html')
```

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize the inputs from the user to prevent SQL injection. Especially since you're not using SQLAlchemy but rather direct execution.

Comment: Set `unique=True` on the `username` field.

Comment: @snakecharmerb if you don't provide any validation, that will just raise an error, so you'd have to wrap it in a try/except block. it would be easier to check the database _before_ adding a user.

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 then you risk a race condition, where another request inserts the username between the check and the insert.

Answer (score 1):

Query your database to see if the username or email has already been taken by another user. Assuming your database is called `users`, here is how to validate an email or username:

```py
email = request.form.get("email")
user = users.query.filter(users.email==email).first()
if user != None: # the query has returned a user
    flash("Please use a different email.")
    return render_template("register.html")
```

Do the same for your username, maybe name or whatever you want to be unique.

It might be a good idea to add `unique=True` to the database model columns which need to be unique, to make sure that even if your validation doesn't catch the error, it won't be possible to enter a duplicate into the database.

Comment: `if user != None` could just be `if user:`

Comment: Where exactly can I add the query? My database name is todo_list with a table called users which is where user data is stored. I am still struggling to make it work, need serious help.

Comment: @Leeuw Add that to your validation on the `app.route()`, before your `if password == confirm`.

Comment: Answers and comments provided here are good, just adding some experience from my development (not answering your question directly though):  

- use SQLAlchemy model instead of directly inserting to database. as mentioned by smallpants, otherwise you **have to** sanitize your inputs. also, as said in @onsieuralfonse64 and snakechamerb, then you can call saving in try/except block.  

- i would recommand to use WTForms for you registration form. You can then easily validate on form submit and return info to user.

Answer (score 0):

```
@auth.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup_post():
    email = request.form.get('email')
    firstname = request.form.get('first_name')
    lastname = request.form.get('last_name')
    phone = request.form.get('phone')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    re_password = request.form.get('password1')
    created_date = date.today()
    if re_password != password:
        flash("Not same password, please check again!")
    else:
        user = User.query.filter_by(
            email=email).first()  # if this returns a user, then the email already exists in database
        if user:  # if a user is found, we want to redirect back to signup page so user can try again
            return redirect(url_for('auth.signup'))
        else:
            # create a new user with the form data. Hash the password so the plaintext version isn't saved.
            new_user = User(email=email, phone=phone,created_date=created_date, firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, password=generate_password_hash(password, method='sha256'))
            # add the new user to the database
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
```

So if you want to check username, you can use the code

```
user = User.query.filter_by(
            username=username).first()
if user:  # if a user is found, we want to redirect back to signup page so user can try again
            return redirect(url_for('auth.signup'))
        else:


CONTINUE TODO SOMETHING
```

I think you should to make the short code for SQLAlchemy

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

And user [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and creat Models.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)  # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(30))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(30))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(10))
    password = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

[Full guilder you can see here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login)

Comment: A side note: the SQLAlchemy command `filter_by()` is used in things like the Flask Mega-Tutorial, but it is much preferred to use `filter()`, as that is more consistent with `order_by()` etc

Answer (score 0):

you have just to put your email as unique when creating your database
using sql :`CREATE TABLE users ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email TEXT UNIQUE, firstname TEXT NOT NULL, lastname TEXT NOT NULL, hash TEXT NOT NULL); CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_email ON users (email)`

i using SQL from cs50 not SQLAlchemy